# Coldfusion Addition of variables from queries

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have a query and I am trying to add the individual values that outputs in the end.

This is the query

```
<cfloop query="score">
  <cfset scorefinal = score * answerweight>
  <cfif getCategories.surveyidfk eq score.surveyidfk and getCategories.categoryidfk eq score.categoryidfk>
    <cfset result = getcategories.cweight * scorefinal>
    <cfdump var="#result#">
  </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

This code outputs 1.5 2.5 1.3

I need a method that will add these values in another variable that will allow me to show only a single value in the end.

I was thinking to store these values in an array and then add the elements of the array but I am pretty sure that there is a faster and easier way to do it.

Comment: Is there a reason you wouldn't sum the values sql side?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't used ColdFusion in a long time, but this should do it:

```
<cfset finalScore = 0>
<cfloop query="score">
    <cfset scorefinal = score * answerweight>
    <cfif getCategories.surveyidfk eq score.surveyidfk and getCategories.categoryidfk eq score.categoryidfk>
        <cfset result = getcategories.cweight * scorefinal>
        <cfset finalScore = finalScore + result>
        <cfdump var="#result#">
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
<cfdump var="#finalScore#">
```

Comment: +1 To be fancy you could put <cfset finalScore += result> ;-)